# Downsampling non-uniform 1D signals

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two 1D numpy arrays: `x` and `y` where `x` holds locations on the x-axis for my samples `y`. Assuming that `x` spans `minX` and `maxX`, I would like to sample both arrays at regular intervals, e.g. `np.linspace(minX, maxX, 1000)`.

How can I do that in numpy? Can I perhaps solve this problem with 1D interpolation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[np.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) performs 1D linear interpolation:

```
newx = np.linspace(minX, maxX, 1000)
newy = np.interp(newx, x, y)
```

Or, using [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) you can interpolate with splines. For example, `kind='cubic'` gives you third order spline interpolation:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
newx = np.linspace(minX, maxX, 1000)
newy = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(newx)
```